# accessing values of web.config file in newly created project under existing .net application hosted on IIS

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, iis-7

I have a classic asp project, which is hosted on IIS with .Net 4.0 framework. The project uses some .net dlls so thats why the root has a bin folder and web.config file.

I have created a new .net project and trying to access the appSettings connection string  key from the root config file, since i want to keep the connection string at one place.
But i am getting the below address:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I have put the my project dll in the main root bin folder. I have also deleted the config file from my project so we have only one config file in the root. so the entire site is working with single app pool.

Please let me know how i can access the values of root config file in my newly created project.

Answer (score 0):

Add reference:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
```

In config file:

```
< configuration >
    < appSettings >
        < add key="KeyName" value="KeyValue" />
    </ appSettings >
</ configuration >
```

In your code:

```
string value = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["KeyName"];
```

value should be "KeyValue"

Having said that, there are very few cases where accessing the config file for data is the best solution

Comment: Hi my bad i was trying to access connectionStrings tag value with the AppSettings and thats why it was giving me NUll reference exception. I am good now.